# Use Amazon RDS Globals in .env in a Symfony 4 project

Tags: amazon-web-services, symfony, global

I have set up a Symfony 4 project and deployed it to AWS.
The credentials for the database connection are available via the server globals. Is there a way to access those variables directly from the **.env** file? If not, what is the best approach to connect to the database without using hardcoded credentials?

Basically I want to define my connection variables like this so that I can assign them to the **DATABASE_URL**.

```
RDS_HOSTNAME=$_SERVER['RDS_HOSTNAME']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you could access those variables directly from the `.env` file. As below. With this way, you are supposed to install `Dotenv Bundle`

`RDS_HOSTNAME=getenv("RDS_HOSTNAME")`

BUT, this approach is the best way on development. While you are running on production, they recommend environment variable approach.

`Symfony Dotenv can be used in any environment of your application: development, testing, staging and even production. However, in production it's recommended to configure real environment variables to avoid the performance overhead of parsing the .env file for every request.`

https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dotenv.html